# Testing SQL methods that don't use transactions?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Suppose I have a database method that looks like this:

```
public void insertRow(SqlConnection c)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into myTable values(@dt)",c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt",DbType.DateTime)).Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Now suppose I want to test this method. So, I write a test case that attempts to wrap this method inside a transaction, so that I can rollback the change after testing the result of the insertion:

```
public void testInsertRow()
{
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("connection.string.here");
    SqlTransaction trans = c.BeginTransaction();
    insertRow();
    // do something here to evaluate what happened, e.g. query the DB
    trans.Rollback();
}
```

This however fails to work, because:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Is there a way to accomplish this, without having to rewrite every single database method to accept a transaction, and then rewrite every single call to pass `null` into the method for the transaction?

For example, this would work:

```
public void insertRow(SqlConnection c, SqlTransaction t)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into myTable values(@dt)",c))
    {
        if (t != null) cmd.Transaction = t;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt",DbType.DateTime)).Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    c.Close();
}
```

But then, I have to either rewrite each and every call to the database method to include that `null` parameter, or write override signatures for each and every database method that automatically pass in a `null`, e.g.

```
public void insertRow(SqlConnection c) { insertRow(c, null); }
```

What's the best way to allow transaction-based testing of database calls?

Comment: [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Seems to me that you are closing your connection before rolling back.

Comment: @Lunyx you're right, that wasn't supposed to be in there. Removing it of course doesn't solve the issue, but thanks for pointing it out - edited.

Comment: Why don't you test it by having `SqlConnection c` point to a test database?

Comment: @DanBracuk Because I do not want the data to persist. This would be an integration test - we'd run through a test case by inserting records, querying the records, etc. but we don't want anything left behind. Obviously the testing is against a test database to begin with, but I'd like to be able to leave that database in its initial state without manually cleaning up every single time I run tests (which sometimes may fail and leave the database inconsistent)

Comment: @fdmillion I beleive what Dan was saying is you use a test database and restore from a backup before you start running a batch of tests to get the database in to a known good state. Every testing framework out there has a way to run some bit of code before the first test starts and after the last test finishes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This doesn't allow for parallel testing. If I use transactions and multiple connections I can run tests in parallel. I might be doing "testing" wrong, but I'm using C#'s test tools to write these database tests. I do have a stored proc that reverts the test database to a known state, but since test A, without a transaction, would alter the database, test B would then run against the (partial) remnants of test A. If test A were in a transaction, test B would still see the pristine database.

Comment: So, TransactionScope mentioned in first comment does not help?

Comment: No, If test A where in a transaction test B would be blocked till test A rolled back its transaction (unless you are using snapshot isolation for the transactions). And doing a new TransactionScope with the `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` option per test method would do the exact situation you where talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746(v=vs.110).aspx) to add the connections automatically in to a transaction

```
public void testInsertRow()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("connection.string.here");
        insertRow(c);
        // do something here to evaluate what happened, e.g. query the DB

        //do not call scope.Complete() so we get a rollback.
    }   
}
```

Now this will cause tests to block each other if you have multiple parallel tests running. If you database is set up to support it you could do Snapshot isolation so updates from concurrent tests won't lock each other out.

```
public void testInsertRow()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                                                        new TransactionOptions(IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("connection.string.here");
        insertRow(c);
        // do something here to evaluate what happened, e.g. query the DB

        //do not call scope.Complete() so we get a rollback.
    }   
}
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly. Only thing I notice is that if I declare the connection outside of the scope, the scope doesn't seem to work. So if I want to rollback and then perform more actions, looks like I have to open a new connection. Not a big deal, just noticed it.